# My OWIN middleware gets skipped?

Tags: c#, owin, katana

I have the following code

```
public class Startup
{
    public void Configuration(IAppBuilder appBuilder)
    {
        appBuilder.Use((owinContext, next) =>
        {
            return owinContext.Response.WriteAsync("1").ContinueWith(task => next()).ContinueWith(task => owinContext.Response.WriteAsync("4"));
        });
        appBuilder.Use((owinContext, next) => owinContext.Response.WriteAsync("2").ContinueWith(task => next()) );
        appBuilder.Use((owinContext, next) => owinContext.Response.WriteAsync("3").ContinueWith(task => next()));
    }
}
```

When I access the output (self hosted web app), I get one of the following:

- 1234
- 1243
- 124

The ordiring doesn't matter much, but what's bothering me is when "3" doesn't get displayed (**124** is displayed withouth **3**)

How comes it gets skipped?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your `ContinueWith(task=>next())` calls are wrapping a task within a task. You may want to make use of the [`Unwrap`](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/dd780917(v=vs.110).aspx) extension method.

Basically, these continuations are running after your first `WriteAsync` method has completed. They're then executing `next()` but that's returning a new `Task` than nothing is then waiting for it to complete.

Something like:

```
appBuilder.Use((owinContext, next) =>
{
    return owinContext.Response.WriteAsync("1").ContinueWith(task => next()).Unwrap()
                   .ContinueWith(task => owinContext.Response.WriteAsync("4")).Unwrap();
});
appBuilder.Use((owinContext, next) => owinContext.Response.WriteAsync("2")
                   .ContinueWith(task => next()).Unwrap() );
appBuilder.Use((owinContext, next) => owinContext.Response.WriteAsync("3")
                   .ContinueWith(task => next()).Unwrap() );
```

(I even managed to miss one more needed `Unwrap` in this first one, where another `ContinueWith` was creating a `Task<Task>`)

Alternatively, I'd consider making use of `async` lambdas, which would probably clean this code up far more. Something like:

```
appBuilder.Use(async (owinContext, next) =>
{
    await owinContext.Response.WriteAsync("1");
    await next();
    await owinContext.Response.WriteAsync("4");
});
appBuilder.Use(async (owinContext, next) => {
    await owinContext.Response.WriteAsync("2");
    await next();
});
appBuilder.Use(async (owinContext, next) => {
    await owinContext.Response.WriteAsync("3");
    await next();
});
```